Need Help Configuring Cloudflare for SaaS with Custom Domains and SSL
I have created a SaaS eCommerce application hosted on the domain:
apps.bb.com.

My goal is to allow clients to connect their custom domains (e.g., www.brand.com) to my platform apps.bb.com.
For a white-label solution. I want to use Cloudflare for SaaS to provide SSL for these custom domains.
Here is my current setup:
My domain apps.bb.com uses Cloudflare nameservers:
gail.ns.cloudflare.com
mark.ns.cloudflare.com

I want to achieve the following:
Create a subdomain on my app like brand.bb.com.
Redirect this subdomain to www.brand.com using a CNAME record.
I have tried to follow the setup guide here: Cloudflare for SaaS Documentation, but I find it quite confusing. Specifically, I'm having trouble with the following:
Creating the fallback URL
Linking the fallback URL to my platform
Can anyone provide a step-by-step guide or point me in the right direction to achieve this configuration? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
I tried using the documentation and creating fall back url but it didnt worked
